# Select column from Mongodb in golang using mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

As I know, we can use

```
> db['twitter-3'].find({}, {"text": 1})
```

to select all texts in collection.

How can we use mgo to find specific field in golang?
I tried

```
var result []string
err = conn.Find(bson.M{}, bson.M{"text", 1}).All(&result)
```

But it is not correct.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the query [Select](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Query.Select) method to specify the fields to return:

```
var result []struct{ Text string `bson:"text"` }
err := c.Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"text": 1}).All(&result)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
for _, v := range result {
     fmt.Println(v.Text)
}
```

In this example, I declared an anonymous type with the one selected field. It's OK to use a type with all document fields.

Comment: In the structure, what does `bson:"text"` stand for? Is there any reference that I can check to have a better understand for this?

Comment: Thanks! How does one select multiple columns? Just adding Select(bson.M{"text": 1, "anotherColumn":1}) does not work.

Comment: why `it returns in`type map[][] ` not as json

Answer (score 2):

to select multiple fields:

```
var result []struct{
    Text string `bson:"text"`
    Otherfield string `bson:"otherfield"`
}

err := c.Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"text": 1, "otherfield": 1}).All(&result)
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
for _, v := range result {
    fmt.Println(v.Text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result interface{}
err = c.Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"text": 1}).All(&result)
```